# Stylesheet for printing, background-color ignored

Tags: html, css

I create a table where I cycle between giving each tr the class "odd" and "even". In my stylesheet I've got this:

```
table tbody tr.odd {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

This works from the browser but not when printing. Everything else in my media stylesheet works except this background-color.

I have colors enabled for printing, I can print images with colors... so?

Comment: Firefox 11. Let me try in Chrome...

Comment: please see the those page who print you ?

Comment: I had problems printing some coursework a while back. IIRC, I used IE9 to print with background colours. I think Opera supports them too, although I'm not sure about the most recent versions of FF and Chrome.

Comment: try add a "td" table tbody tr.odd td {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, most browsers ignore CSS background colours and images when printing. This can only be overridden by changing the setting in the browser, if the browser even has such an option (some don't, as Quentin points out).

Comment: And not all browsers have such a preference these days.

Comment: If you want Images in your printing-documents, you should use `<img>`, that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve background color of a div by in print preview. The border color in `divForBgColor:before` will be the background color of `divForBgColor`.

```
.divForBgColor {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.divForBgColor:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 9999px solid #f1f2f2;
    z-index: -1;
}
```